# how to run dotnet core's standalone program on mac

Tags: json, ruby, rest, .net-core

a rudimentary question, but please let me know.

I want to run the following program which will process and return the result by json when accessed by GET or POST.

[FileManagerController.cs](https://github.com/servocoder/RichFilemanager/blob/master/connectors/asp/FileManagerController.cs)

For example, in PHP you just need to place it in the htdocs folder of Apache.

I would like to do the same thing with dot net core mvc.

but I don't know what kind of words to search.

Also, in the near future we would like ruby to work the same way in another project.(In a way that doesn't use a framework such as rails)

So, please tell me how to find out how to run various languages alone on a web server.

Comment: I don't know .net core, but it looks like you need to use their [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) server.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ “ in PHP you just need to place it in the htdocs folder of Apache” statement is wrong. It has nothing to do with the programming language, it depends on web server config only.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you for answering. I will investigate.

Comment: @mudasobwa I did not know. I thought PHP would work only with Apache. (Java often combines Apache and Tomcat, but does it mean the same?)

Comment: Well, PHP can work with many web servers, and Apache can work with many languages; but even when we are talking LAMP, it’s a responsibility of _Apache_ not _PHP_ on what to do with this files.

Comment: "you just need to place it in the htdocs folder" - what you don't see is that for this to work this easily, you also need to install apache and configure it to run PHP. Which was done for you by OS maintainers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a "project" (file type `.csproj`) that you can build and run on your machine. Check out the [Getting Started with ASP.NET](https://www.asp.net/get-started) page for instructions to install the SDK and create a new project and run it.

To run your code file above, you can:

1. `$ dotnet new mvc`
2. Copy the above FileManagerController.cs file into the generated `Controllers` folder.
3. `$ dotnet run`

Your app will be running on `http://localhost:5000`, you can hit your web site using the url `/FileManager`.